# Localize jQuery variable while building a widget. How do I refer to jQuery in another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, scope

I'm following this [tutorial on building a widget](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/)

IN that tutorial, he's testing whether jquery exists on the page and, if not, loading it.

I've recreated his code [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQBwt/)

I've added another object, CssLoader, but I'm unable to use jquery inside that object. You can see that my alert is not working.

How should I ensure jquery is available in CssLoader and any other objects I create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tweaked your code

```
var CssLoader = (function(){
    var $=''; //the global $ inside CssLoader
    function init($, cssPathArray){ // Receive the jquery in the first argument
        $=jq; // assign jQuery to global $, so it'll be available inside CssLoader
        alert( $('body') );            
    }

    return {
        init : init
    };
})();
```

And inside function `main` call `CssLoader.init` as follows

```
CssLoader.init($, ['cssPath1', 'cssPath2']); // Pass the jquery in the first argument
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/xQBwt/3/)

Comment: Thanks. That will work, but it will mean I'll have to pass jquery into every object I create (that requires it). I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: No, you should call init first so it'll be available globally but this is nit the proper way, I've just tweaked your code a little bit. Check the demo, there are two alerts. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

At the first, you are localizing jQuery and then try to call it from another anonymous function. Why are you trying to do this?

However, these docs should help: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring